# VBA making cells mandatory based on previous cell entry

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Is there a way of making a number of cells mandatory based on the entry of a cell? The cell contents may vary.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Show your work, a screenshot of sorts. You chose, "triple scoop", you must enter 3 flavors? Where are we going with this? Mandatory in what way? What is this cell or cells or range of cells criteria? Set up a great  question for best solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You would create a "BeforeSave" sub in your workbook VBA. To do this:

- Open Excel VBA (Alt+F11)
- Click ThisWorkbook
- There are two bars above the code window, click the first bar and select "Workbook"
- Click the second bar and click "Before save" This will fill in your sub for you

Then add the following (Assuming Cell 1A was to be your reference cell and 2A was mandatory):

```
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(1,1)) Then
       If Cells(2,1).Value = "" Then
          MsgBox "Cell 2A requires user input before saving"
          Cancel = True
       End if
    End if
```

You can then just add elses for any other cells you want to check

Comment: Thanks @Lister. Sorry, I should have mentioned this will need to be done per row. Do you know if there is there any way of it working without doing a BeforeSave?

Comment: Hrmm, a batch job. could you update  your question with an example layout to make life easier? Also are we talking a changing number of rows, or a set row? If you were to do it on a sheet change which is really your only other option each time a user edited a field (Even if it was one you told them to) They would get another message of "Cell X requires changing)