# Making data mandatory on Excel based on previous cell entry

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Trying to make cells mandatory based on previous cell entry.

On screenshot I want to make cells in Columns Y, AA, AD & AE mandatory IF Cells in column X have been completed.

So far I have tried:

`IF Range("X").Value = ("Mon") And Range("Y").Value = "" And Range("AA").Value = "" And Range("AD").Value = "" And Range("AE").Value = "" Then msgBox ("Please complete other cells on this row").`

But this doesn't seem to be working. do you have any ideas as how to make this work?

[image: spreadsheet example]

Comment: What is `Range("X")` do you have a name  "X" defined in the spreadsheet? Where is this code located? Is it started manually or located in an event procedure? According to your conditions currently your msgbox would apppear only if "X" contain "Mon" and ALL THE CELLS Y, AA, AD AE are empty (you may want to use `Range("X").Value = ("Mon") And (Range("Y").Value = "" Or Range("AA").Value = "" Or Range("AD").Value = "" Or Range("AE").Value = "")`)

Comment: Hi, no. Its Column X - we'd like it for X1,X2,X3.... is there a way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Comment: It's excel 2010

Comment: I've asked more question, not just because I'm bored, but because they're required for the solution, please answer all of them

Comment: Hi, It will located in an event procedure. The second bit is more what I want. To make sure nobody misses entering any data. The code is in VBA in the Sheet 1 (input) tab. Range X will be selected from a dropdown list - Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun.

Comment: The better way to do this is to use conditional formatting to cause the missing cells to have a yellow or red background color.  Users can always close excel, or reboot computer, so "mandatory" is not fully possible by code.  Instead, you can have a cell say complete and with the highlight make sure users understand need to finish.  Having a cell say "Complete" and highlighting cells missing info does not need macros.

Comment: @bvaughn To prevent this scenario you could use the [`Workbook_BeforeClose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194765.aspx) event which fires when the Excel file is closed

Comment: You've got different suggestions. Probably because the flow of activities isn't clear. According to your question: user enter something in column "x", then before he would have the chance to fill other columns too, he got a message that those columns are compulsory (he probably knows, but he can't bee quick enough). Probably you haven't yet received answer, because your process doesn't really make sense

Comment: Close your last question. It's exactly the same: http://superuser.com/questions/1108275/vba-making-cells-mandatory-based-on-previous-cell-entry